# Unable to send data by Ajax request from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to send some data from my chrome extension to my Php page, by Jquery Ajax request. The request is successfully sent but the data values are empty.
i.e. I am trying to send the value of the #urlname but I am unable to do it. Its working fine when I run it from the page(i.e. not from chrome extension) but its not sending the values when I am using it from chrome extension.
I have already spent lots of time on it to get it fixed,tried different methods to send request, but was not successful and got  same results everytime.
I think I am missing something on the chrome extension part(some security issue, I don't know). I am new to this and this is my first extension.
 Please help

Here are a few details

**manifest.json**

```
  {
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "First Extention",
"description": "POST details of the current page to a remote endpoint.",
"version": "0.1",
"content_scripts": [{
  "js": ["contentscript.js"]

}],
"web_accessible_resources": ["script.js"],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
    "http://www.example.com/",
    "contextMenus",
    "bookmarks",
    "tabs", 
    "http://*/", 
    "https://*/"
]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<form id="url">
<label for="url">A bar</label>
<input id="urlname" name="url" type="text" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form> 
<div id="result"></div>

<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
 <script src="js/background.js"></script>
```

***background.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

 chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    var tabId = tab.id;
    var tabUrl = tab.url;
//var tabTitle=tab.title;

   document.getElementById("urlname").value=tabUrl;
   //document.getElementById("title").value=tabTitle;

   chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: "10+"});
 });
 });
```

**main.js**

```
$("#url").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();


$("#result").html('');


var values = $(this).serialize();


$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.example.com/adddata.php",
    type: "post",
    data: values,
    success: function(text){

        alert(text);
        $("#result").html('Submitted successfully');
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("failure");
        $("#result").html('There is error while submit');
    }
});
});
```

**adddata.php**

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
echo $_POST['url']."hello";
**
 //
  mysql insert into database query and rest of the php code.

 //
 ?>
```

the response is "hello". instead it should be `$_POST['url']`(value)+hello. But the
  $_POST['url'] is empty why? Therefore i am unable to perform the rest of the php
  operation.

Thanks

Comment: `document.getElementById("urlname")`: there is no such element on the background page.

Comment: oh..its already included in the popup.html. i forgot to add it earlier i have updated it..anyidea about why i am unable to send the data?